# Fluid simulation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulation, fluid-dynamics

I have a (vertical) cylinder in Matlab, built using the patch command. For every 'level' of the cylinder I have a different radius, so that the 3D plot displays something like this:

[image: blah]

Also, I used a sequence of images to simulate the movement of the structure (the radius at every level changes overtime).

What I would like to do now is the simulation of a certain mass of fluid passing through the cylinder. Say, the first image will show the fluid (a sphere?) on top, and the successive ones will show the fluid following the shape of the cylinder.

I tried to solve this problem by simply colouring the facets of the cylinder, but I would need something more "hydraulic-like".

How can I approach this problem? How fluids can be treated/modelled in Matlab environment?

Any suggestion/tip would be appreciated.